# iOS Facebook API/SDK Wrapper?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wrapper

I've been looking for a good iOS Facebook API/SDK Wrapper, can't find any.

I need to be able to (with a few lines of code, not the insanely needed by Facebook's API):

- Login user
- Logout user
- Get user's likes
- Invite Friend to app
- Maybe post to user's wall (this has been causing problems to other apps so not sure will actually implement)
- Get user's friends
- Get user's basic info (e-mail, name, etc.)

Is there any wrapper simplifying the absurd vanilla API?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/
This should help and it is Facebook's official api.
Here's the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

Comment: Thanks for the links, I started trying them out but I'm still looking for an easy wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use portions of ShareKit for this (be sure to abide by their license): https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/tree/master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook

This doesn't do everything you asked, but it's a (clean) starting point at least: https://github.com/mobitar/Zuckerkit

This does a bit more, but hasn't been updated in a year: https://github.com/sinnerschrader-mobile/S2M-Facebook-iOS

Answer (score 0):

I found this lib: https://github.com/lucascorrea/SCFacebook

It seems to use a not that outdated version of the iOS SDK (3.18 vs. current 3.21), is available on cocoapods and seems to cover many of your required API features.

I haven't used the lib my self, but i am considering it next time i have to develop an iOS App which needs to connect to facebook.